# Small resource storage database for embedded project

Tags: c++, database, embedded, storage

I am working on a very specific platform without an OS. The task at hand requires storing resources such as strings and bitmaps, all in raw binary data separately from code binary to accesses it at runtime.

We have direct storage block reading and writing mechanisms implementation but no file systems. The language is mostly C++ without templates and exceptions which is a platform compiler restriction, so no stl and boost.

Given those restrictions i need a simple database storage approach to store aforementioned resources on disk and access them using some kind of a key. I have rolled my own for the time being which uses a simple flat binary storage and can be addressed with a numerical id - a table index to get to the offset of the resource's raw bytes. However this is really inconvenient to use since i have to manually keep track of resource ids and make sure they are allocated sequentially from 0 and up.

I am thinking maybe there are already better library solutions out there that can be relatively easily modified to fit the requirements and can be integrated with the codebase before i will start rolling out a hash function so i can use short strings as keys? Storage is constant once generated and only accessed for reading.

EDIT: I guess what i need is a substitute for a resource dll that can work (or easily made to work) without a runtime linker and a file system.

Comment: What platform has no OS?

Comment: @John Dibling - this is not your usual "recommendation" question, but more one of how to solve a particular, atypically constrained problem (yet not, from an embedded perspective, one that seems like it should be unusual - lots of embedded platforms have no OS)

Comment: It's an interesting question, and I hope you find an answer.  But at the end of the day you're asking for library recommendations or generalized how-do-I-X recommendations, and that sort of question doesn't fit well with SO.

Comment: When you say a resource DLL, it makes me think read-only.  That strikes me as simplifying the problem a lot - you can use build system tools to optimize packing different size pieces, and just have a lookup table of start pointers and lengths to process at runtime.  You could even look at something like the compressed cpio archives linux uses to store boot 'filesystem' images.

Comment: I'll remove my previous comment, but it it impossible for me to remove my VTC.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - you know, you are absolutely right. I got too caught up with the runtime and completely forgot that i can just make up a simple key=value resource file, pack those resource values one by one in a binary image, generate a header file with keys #defined as offsets into the start of the resource value, flash that image into predefined position and offset away in the code. I can add a lookup table if recompiling to localize would prove too much hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your constraints of custom OS, specific data, and constrained resources. I think your only option is a roll your own.

quick and dirty: http://elliottback.com/wp/hashmap-implementation-in-c/

Followup edit:
  Use the same code in your tools phase for conversion from XML or other datasources to your "hash map". Differences discovered in use could be recorded, uploaded, collected, and fed back into the build.

This may be a "generic" problem, but it often occurs in embedded development. There's a point where what you want conflicts with what you have and a sanity check is needed. Usually a conservative "simple" solution is a better start, and it seems you already have one.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using SQLite? I've found it to work well as a small localized database, and it doesn't require an "instance" or constantly running process, just a file. It integrates quite easily into C++.

http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: I feel that an actual SQL engine is an overkill for this task. What i need is a substitute for a resource dll that can work without a runtime linker and a file system.

Comment: Was wondering about that too, but remember there's no OS and no filesystem, so it may take a while to implement equivalents to required system functionality before porting it is possible.

Comment: True, and I'd imagine it'd take some tweaking in that scenario, but it's open source and could be a starting point. It looks like the further clarification is that it doesn't have to be a database per se, so that does open it up some more.

Comment: SQLite for this problem seems to be whacking a mosquito with a sledgehammer.

Answer (score 0):

Having tackled this problem several times before, I'm in agreement with the "roll your own" answers.   Without knowing more (your platform, IDE, application, etc.), I can only offer a point of reference.

Our strategy built binary *packages* containing screen layouts, sounds, bitmaps, and font tables.  Each package contained a header identifying the number and type of resources stored in the package, as well as the offsets pointing to the beginning of each resource.  (The structure of the package metadata was loosely inspired by the JPEG/TIFF headers with IFD blocks, etc).  In a couple of the implementations, we were loading from NAND flash, so I associated 16-bit CRCs with each resource. Other implementations added a "compressed" flag to identify resources that were compressed using zlib.

From a workflow perspective: our IDE provided a python interpreter, which allowed me to implement scripts to automate construction of the resource package.  This also allowed me to embed the resulting package directly into the hex file comprising the binary image.